# Query users by capability - uninstall/deactivate callback

Tags: multisite, users, user-meta, uninstallation, wp-user-query

### The situation

Running on MU, I'm writing an open source/publically and freely available plugin. As I used `add_screen_option()` to allow users to easily setup the admin page to their likings, I'm left with a bunch of user meta data. Now the page itself is restricted to users with the `manage_options` capability, so only those have got this meta entry when they adjusted the `per page` value for a list table.

> [image: The "per page" Screen Option]

### The task

To allow the plugin to leave a clean state in case some chooses to remove the plugin, I added a deactivation and an uninstall hook callback that should loop through user data and remove the meta entries. Now I could simply loop through all users, check their meta value and so on, but this would hardly fail on sites with lots of users and end in a time out (remember, Meta tables are `JOIN`ed).

### The idea (so far)

To make it short, here's what I thought: The MU install has a `user` and a `usermeta` table. And from what I can see, there're not really capabilities saved, but role names - WordPress makes no difference between roles and capabilities here. Fun as it is, it seems that there're different things I have to consider:

**User can be…**

- superadmin
- registered on multiple sites
- registered on multiple sites with different roles
- registered on multiple sites with the same role, but role has different capabilities on different sites
- ...?

The problem starts with those different possibilities and goes further, when you look at ho the capabilities are saved in a Network/MU setup:

```
{$wpdb->prefix}capabilities
```

Or

```
{$wpdb->prefix}{get_current_blog_id()}_capabilities
```

So for what would one query?

```
$query_args = array(
);
$query = new WP_User_Query( $query_args );
$users = $query->results;
if ( empty( $users ) )
    return;

var_dump( $users );
```

#### EDIT

Just a first attempt to query for role names with a specific capability:

```
    $roles = new WP_Roles();
    $roles = wp_list_pluck( $roles->role_objects, 'capabilities' );
    $results = array();
    foreach ( $roles as $role => $caps )
    {
        array_key_exists( 'manage_options', $caps )
            AND $results[] = $role;
    }
    var_dump( $results );

    # Even if it's smarter then above loop, it won't work and 
    # throw an error in core files.
    $roles = array_filter( wp_list_pluck( $roles, 'manage_options' ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually much easier than I originally thought - just doing a `WP_User_Query` for a meta value (meta arrays are supported as well, like for the other query classes).

```
public function on_deactivate()
{
    $meta_key = 'tools_page_tsi_per_page';
    $query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => $meta_key ) );

    if ( empty( $query->results ) )
        return;

    foreach ( wp_list_pluck( $query->results, 'ID' ) as $user_id )
        delete_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key );
}
```